# Self extract or something?

Tags: python

I'm trying to sell a very important file, because of that, I planned to create a 
"confirm and extract" python script, so that my python script will only extract 
the file only once and only when my client has paid.

Now my problem is, can I do this?

- read my important file
- encode it with base64
- compress and encrypt it (to make my script small size as possible)
- and then when extracting:

  - decrypt, decompress and decode it' base64
  - and write the date to a file

Is there any option better than this? I just don't want to download anything, so that the only way 
they'll be getting my file is through the (compiled to executable) python script

Comment: Why not just send a password-protected ZIP file?

Comment: Why is only extractable once a requirement? Seems hard to implement if the client has full control of the file. Would be easier if it was a server serving that file once and only once given the password was supplied

Comment: @DyZ You could in theory brute force the zip's password, no?

Comment: @francium No more likely than reverse-engineer a python script.

Comment: @DyZ, I'm not crypto expert here, but a script need not be obfuscated to be secure. See open source GnuPG for example

Comment: @francium: You could in theory brute force the encryption algorithm's key. A sufficiently complex password with a good key derivation algorithm is just a way of generating the encryption key after all; a strong password should be no easier to brute force than whatever raw encryption scheme you'd like to reinvent.

Comment: By the way, whats the point of base64 encoding? It adds nothing to the solution whatsoever. Also, the one-time extraction is meaningless: once the file is extracted, you have no control over it.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/gammazero/pymakeself.  This has the option to encrypt a file using a password, and uses AES ctr-mode encryption.  The crypto implementation is purely in python, so while much slower than a compiled implementation, it does not require anything to be downloaded or compiled on the target system. It embeds the compressed/encrypted archive into a python executable, so that all that is needed is that executable.  On extraction, it will run an install script if provided.